# Break matrix into averaged time bins using R

Tags: r

I need to convert a matrix `x` like this:

```
head(x)
       Age    d18O   d13C   
1     0.000   3.28   0.880   
2     0.000   3.58   0.150   
3     0.002   3.16   0.960    
4     0.002   2.91   3.228    
5     0.004   3.33   0.880    
6     0.004   3.16   3.328

tail(x)
           Age      d18O       d13C 
14883    66.3037    1.00       2.03    
14884    66.3159    1.02       1.70    
14885    66.3800    0.62       2.01    
14886    67.0073    1.30       1.23    
14887    67.2391    1.31       1.30      
14888    67.5173    1.36       1.35
```

into a matrix, containing 0.5 time bins with mean values of each of the variables, such as:

```
      Age     count(x$d18O)   mean(x$d18O)
1       0      500            4.1003
2       0.5    522            4.079464
3       1      412            4.032743
4       1.5    366            3.810601
5       2      498            3.749257
6       2.5    608            3.649063
.       .       .                .
.       .       .                .
```

Age is given in Million of years.

Comment: Try using `cut` on `Age` and then just aggregate according it while calculating `length` and `mean`. See `?aggregate` or the `data.table` and `dplyr` packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(age_bucket = cut(Age, seq(min(Age), max(Age), by = 0.05), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(age_bucket) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean_d18O = mean(d18O))
```

Comment: the group_by(age_bucket) won't work for me since `Error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"`

Comment: @ShawnMehan - fixed - was missing a parens.

Comment: also note that `d18O` should actually be `d180` but I can't edit your answer with only two subs.

Comment: Great work @JasonAizkalns! Thanks! I really appreciate that.  It's actually d18O (O from Oxygen).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sdf=split(x,cut(x$Age,seq(0,max(x$Age)*1.01,by=.5)))
do.call(rbind,lapply(sdf,function(sx)c(length(sx$d18O),mean(sx$d18O))))
```

you will get something similar to:

> ```
> (23,23.5]    0        NaN
> (23.5,24]    4  2.9500345
> (24,24.5]    1  6.9320712
> (24.5,25]    2  3.0219788
> (25,25.5]    2  3.7149871
> (25.5,26]    1  1.9051732
> (26,26.5]    2  3.1865066
> (26.5,27]    1  3.9982569
> ```